# Обработчик нажатий элементов PreferenceActivity

Tags: android

У меня есть preferenceScreen

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/category_additional" />
<Preference
    android:key="share"
    android:summary="@string/share_this_app"
    android:title="@string/share" />
<Preference
    android:key="rate_app"
    android:summary="@string/rate_app_summary"
    android:title="@string/rate_app_title" />
```

Реализовывал разными способами обработчик нажатия, но ничего не происходит. Буду благодарен, если подскажите в чем ошибка. (Если действия в обработчике вешаю на другую кнопку, то все работает)

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
}


@Override
public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
    switch (preference.getKey()) {
        case "rate_app":
            AppUtilities.rateThisApp(this);
        case "share":
            AppUtilities.shareApp(this);
    }
    return true;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я себе делал в активити вставлял фрагмент

```
if(savedInstanceState == null){
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.preference_container, new PreferenceFragment())
                .commit();
    }
```

а фрагменту имплеметил OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener

```
PreferenceFragment extends android.preference.PreferenceFragment
    implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
```

и там в методе `onSharedPreferenceChanged` находишь свою настройку по ключу и работаешь с ней.

```
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {

    if (key.equals(getString(R.string.list_preference_1))) {
        snackbar = Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content),"Размер шрифта изменен", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        View snackBarView = snackbar.getView();
        TextView textView = snackBarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
        textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), android.R.color.white));
        snackbar.show();
    }
```

или же если ничего не нужно менять просто в методе onCreate ^

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

    rateUsButton();
```

и собственно сам метод:

```
private void rateUsButton() {
    Preference rateUsPreference = findPreference(RATE_US);
    rateUsPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse(URL_CONNECT));
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

где RATE_US ключ
а URL - адрес приложения